# Importing Font Awesome in vue-cli webpack project

Tags: sass, webpack-2, vue-cli

I've created clear vue-cli webpack project, installed font-awesome via npm.

Then inside ./assets/scss/styles.scss I'm importing it (@import '~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss';).

When I run npm start there are errors:

```
These relative modules were not found:

* ../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false}!./src/assets/scss/styles.
scss
* ../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0 in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false}!./src/assets/scss
/styles.scss
* ../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.7.0 in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false}!./src/assets/scss
/styles.scss
* ../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0 in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false}!./src/assets/scss
/styles.scss
* ../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0 in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false}!./src/assets/sc
ss/styles.scss
* ../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0 in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false}!./src/assets/scs
s/styles.scss
```

How can I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, it was an easy fix. It was need to include:

```
$fa-font-path: "~font-awesome/fonts";
```

for proper fonts import.

Comment: It was so helpful. Thank you.

Comment: But "font-awesome" npm repository is for Font-Awesome v4.
To use Font-Awesome v5 with npm, see https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/use-with-node-js